# Show that $n$ is a divisor of $[L:K]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $L/K$ be a field extension.

I want to show that if the extension $L/K$ is finite and $a\in L$ has a minimal polynomial of degree $n$, then $n$ is a divisor of $[L:K]$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

We have that $[K(a):K]=\deg \text{Irr}(a,K)=n$ and $K\leq K(a)\leq L$, or not?

Since $L/K$ is finite, we have that $$[L:K]=[K(a):K][L:K(a)]\Rightarrow [K(a):K]\mid [L:K] \Rightarrow n\mid [L:K]$$

Is everything correct? Could I improve something?

Comment: Your solution is perfectly correct. Going further, you can show that the characteristic polynomial of the multiplication map $ x \to ax $ in $ L/K $ (which is of degree $ [L:K] $ by definition) is a power of the minimal polynomial of $ a $.

Comment: Can we just use that $[K(a):K]=\deg \text{Irr}(a,K)=n$ and $K\leq K(a)\leq L$ or do we have to prove it first? $$$$ How can we show that the characteristic polynomial of the multiplication map $x\mapsto ax$ in $L/K$ is a power of the multilication polynomial of $a$ ? I got stuck right now... @Starfall

Comment: Your first statement is a well known fact which follows from the first isomorphism theorem: defining the evaluation map $ K[x] \to K[\alpha] $ and noting that its kernel is $ (f) $, where $ (f) $ is the minimal polynomial of $ \alpha $ over $ K $, gives an isomorphism $ K[x]/(f) \cong K(\alpha) $ since the ideal $ (f) $ is maximal.